# Really bad Accuracy with Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, kaggle

I was trying to solve the [Dogs vs. Cats Redux: Kernels Edition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition) problem on Kaggle. It is a simple image classification problem. However, I am doing worse than a random predictor with a score of 17+. Does anyone know why this might be?

**Neural Network Model**

```
def convolutional_neural_network():
    weights = {
        # 3x3x3 conv => 1x1x8
        'conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 3, 8])),
        # 5x5x8 conv => 1x1x16
        'conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 8, 16])),
        # 3x3x16 conv => 1x1x32
        'conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 32])),
        # 32 FC => output_features
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([(SIZE//16)*(SIZE//16)*32, output_features]))
    }

    biases = {
        'conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8])),
        'conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
        'conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_features]))
    }
    conv1 = tf.add(conv2d(input_placeholder, weights['conv1'], 1), biases['conv1'])
    relu1 = relu(conv1)
    pool1 = maxpool2d(relu1, 4)

    conv2 = tf.add(conv2d(pool1, weights['conv2'], 1), biases['conv2'])
    relu2 = relu(conv2)
    pool2 = maxpool2d(relu2, 2)

    conv3 = tf.add(conv2d(pool2, weights['conv3'], 1), biases['conv3'])
    relu3 = relu(conv3)
    pool3 = maxpool2d(relu3, 2)

    pool3 = tf.reshape(pool3 , shape=[-1, (SIZE//16)*(SIZE//16)*32])

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(pool3, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return output
```

The the output has no activation function.

**Prediction, Optimizer and Loss Function**

```
output_prediction = convolutional_neural_network()
loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(output_prediction, output_placeholder) )
trainer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
optimizer = trainer.minimize(loss)
test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(output_prediction)
```

The images are converted into an numpy array of size **128**x**128**x**3** and fed into the neural network with a batch size of 64.

[Full Code Here](https://github.com/DollarAkshay/Python-Programs/blob/master/Kaggle/Kaggle_Dogs_vs_Cats.py)

**Edit :**  Ran the same code for 200 epochs. No improvement. I did Slightly worse.

Comment: 20 epochs seems like no where near enough ... also you need a pretty big training set for this ... it may take many hours to train ... you might want to look at googles inception model thats already trained (see also https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/ )

Comment: What have you used this loop for? https://github.com/DollarAkshay/Python-Programs/blob/master/Artificial%20Intelligence/Kaggle_Dogs_vs_Cats.py#L124 Why not `np.argmax` or something?

Comment: @Joran Beasley Yeah 20 epochs seems less, but shouldn't it atleast do a decent prediction ? My training set has 25k images. How many epochs do you suggest ? I actually wanted to learn neural networks, thats why I am not using a pre-trained model :)

Comment: see also : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37451880/541038

Comment: @martianwars Well that loop is to take the 2 probabilities, prob for cat and prob for dog and convert them into 1 number between 0 and 1. I did use `np.argmax`, but it returns either 0 or 1.The scoring algorithm for this problem is different and accepts floating values too

Comment: @martianwars Here you go : https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/details/evaluation

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya I think you need like thousands of epochs ... i wish i could be more help ANN is fascinating stuff, but its been many years since i messed with it in earnest

Comment: @JoranBeasley LOL it took me 1 whole day to run 200 epochs XD. Dont think I can run thousands. :P 
Are you really sure there is nothing else I can do to improve the accuracy other than running more epochs ?

Comment: nope im not sure at all :(

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya I'm pretty sure 20 epochs should give you better results than random. Have you checked how your softmax output looks? And whether you are calculating the cat/dog output corresponding to it?

Comment: @martianwars I did actually debug the softmax output. Since the output is raw i get really huge values like `[-65340.88, 454442.98]` which softmax rounds up to `[ 0, 1]`

Comment: Have you checked that the ReLUs actually get reasonable initial values, i.e. > 0? Maybe try with leaky ReLUs that always give a non-zero gradient?

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment but not enough privilege points for that:

Did you normalize your data (i.e. divide the pixels values by 255)? I can't you see doing that in the script.

When you get terrible results like 17 logloss that means your model is always predicting one class with 100% confidence. Usually in this case it's not the architecture or learning rate or number of epochs but rather some silly mistake like forgetting to normalize or mixing up your labels. For this particular problem and given your architecture you should see an accuracy of about 80% and 0.4 logloss within 40 number of epochs. No need for thousands of epochs :)

Comment: I havent normalised the input images from 255 to 1. But does normalization make such a huge difference ?

Comment: Yes it usually does make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Improving accuracy is an art than one task solution, you can try some of these methods:

- try different gradient optimization, SGD, momentum, nestrov, adap, ...
- Try adaptive learning rate
- improve regularization methods L1,L2,dropout, drop connect, ...
- Augment your training data (have more data).
- change your network hyper parameters
- finally if nothing helped change the network structure.

Comment: Although these are some good techniques, this would be applicable for people with 80% accuracy who are trying to achieve 85% accuracy. In my case I am not even getting above 55%

Comment: If you are not convinced so this what the the last point say. change the algorithm/structure. ,